# Unison profiles root/path issues

Tags: mac, ssh, unix, sync, unison

I am trying to sync two folders with each other (one local, one remote) using unison.

If I use a standard command like this..

```
unison -times /Volumes/My\ HD/Work ssh://myremoteserver//volume1/My\ Files/Work
```

... it works. I know it works because it shows all the files which need to be transferred over from x to y.

However if I create a profile for this function like so...

```
# Roots of the synchronization
root = /Volumes/My\ HD
root = ssh://myremoteserver//volume1/My\ Files

# Paths
path = Work

# Some regexps specifying names and paths to ignore
ignore = Path @eaDir
ignore = Name *.DS_Store

log = true
times = true
```

This brings up this message constantly..

```
Looking for changes
Warning: No archive files were found for these roots, whose canonical names are:
    /Volumes/My\ HD
    //Server//volume1/My\ Files
This can happen either
because this is the first time you have synchronized these roots, 
or because you have upgraded Unison to a new version with a different
archive format.  

If you see this message repeatedly, it may be because one of your machines
is getting its address from DHCP, which is causing its host name to change
between synchronizations.  See the documentation for the UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME
environment variable for advice on how to correct this.
```

.. and then says there are no changes to be made.

I'm aware of the tip it mentions above about DHCP, I'm not sure if this applies to me as using the single command `ssh://myremoteserver` works, it only becomes an issue when including it in a .profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because I've used `\` to escape spaces, but these arent needed for .profiles